# WebdriverIO : webdriver: Failed downloading chromedriver v122.0.6261.57: Download failed: server returned code 500

Tags: webdriver-io

> Failed downloading chromedriver v122.0.6261.57: Download failed: server returned code 500.

On executing webdriverIO setup script.
I am new to webdriverIO. how to override the configuration for stable run?

Error Message

[image]

package.json

[image]

> wdio run ./wdio.conf.js

```
Execution of 1 workers started at 2024-02-22T06:37:17.493Z

2024-02-22T06:37:17.538Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2024-02-22T06:37:17.539Z INFO @wdio/utils: Setting up browser driver for: chrome@stable
2024-02-22T06:37:17.540Z INFO @wdio/utils: Setting up browser binaries for: chrome@stable
2024-02-22T06:37:17.543Z INFO webdriver: Downloading Chromedriver v122.0.6261.58
2024-02-22T06:37:17.969Z WARN webdriver: Chromedriver v122.0.6261.58 don't exist, trying to find known good version...
2024-02-22T06:37:18.434Z ERROR webdriver: Failed downloading chromedriver v122.0.6261.57: Download failed: server returned code 500. URL: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/122.0.6261.57/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip, retrying ...
2024-02-22T06:37:18.876Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2024-02-22T06:37:19.132Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2024-02-22T06:37:19.133Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
Error: Error: Failed downloading chromedriver v122.0.6261.57: Download failed: server returned code 500. URL: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/122.0.6261.57/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip, retrying ...
```

Tried specifying the chromedriver version explicitly in the package.json file but the installer refers and tries to download the latest version of chromedriver.

Comment: To be clear for anyone else visiting this, it's not just a matter of setting unsafe-perm or allowing SSL.  This is a true 500 error coming from Google's cache servers since late yesterday.

If your application doesn't absolutely require this then I recommend setting PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD=true until Google gets their cache server issues resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue for something like a week now.

I got around the problem by fixing the browserVersion in the capabilities.

```
{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    browserVersion: '121.0.6167.85',
    [...]
}
```

I'm still interested by a better solution to always have the last version instead of a fixed working version...

Comment: This would only fix the issue if you have that version downloaded in your local cache already. The url for that version you mention is broken as well: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/121.0.6167.85/linux64/chrome-headless-shell-linux64.zip

Answer (score 0):

Version [8.32.2](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/releases/tag/v8.32.2) of the `webdriver` package contains a fix, by changing the URL to download from.

You should upgrade that package in your `package-lock.json` to last version `8.32.3` .